# The mouse scroll wheel event in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I develop a web site that has two parts: the display by list and the map display. 
I have many markers on my map. Now I  need to get the marker's coordinates of my map when the mouse scroll wheel zoom in or zoom out. It's possible by `moveend`. I am not able to do it despite my searches. Anybody can help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you're trying to do as well as what these markers are; Are they [`ol.geom.Point`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html)? **If so**, you can do something like:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt){
    //layerFeatures is a reference of a ol.layer.Vector
    layerFeatures.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
        var geom = feature.getGeometry();
        var coord = geom.getCoordinates(); //this is valid for a ol.geom.Point
        console.info(coord);
    });
});
```

Comment: My markers are the exactly the "ol.geom.Point" .
I have  add more information into my ol.Feature object :

new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(v.geometry.coordinates, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')), id: v.properties.id, name: v.properties.name

Comment: I need to get this informations include into the ol.Feature object the resolution change.

Thanks you very much, your answer is better :)

Comment: Inside the interation `forEachFeature`, you can get any feature property, e.g `feature.get('name')`